# Angle calculation circles

Tags: geometry

I can't seem to figure out the following geometry problem. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: problem in question]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Dear Brian, I understand your remark. However, it was just a question I stumbled across on the internet and given that I haven't had any practice with geometry for some years had no clue how to solve. It just annoyed me that I couldn't solve it and was just curious for the answer and solution method, not so much in solving it myself. Understand that this is by no means a good way to actually challenge yourself, but for me in this case that was not really what it was about. So I was just curious if anyone could solve it (quickly) and luckily received a helpful reply by @Aretino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: see equal angles in the following diagram.

[image]

Comment: So if I reason correctly we can deduce that 2 blue + 2 red = 90 degrees, so given that we are being asked for 1 blue + 1 red the correct answer is 45 degrees? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, exactly: the answer is 45°.